# How to Install Oracle Driver in ODBC?

Tags: oracle11g, odbc, datasource, windows-7-x64

How do I install Oracle ODBC Driver?
When I open my "ODBC Data Source Administrator", then in "User DSN", then I click "Add..." button, the new window named "Create New Data Source" appears. However I cannot find ORACLE Driver in this window.

How should I install the Oracle driver in ODBC so that I can find it in the list option in "Create New Data Source" window? Please kindly help.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle Data Provider for .net drivers are missing. I also faced the same problem.
Download the Oracle Data Provider for .Net from :
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Read the installation instructions and install.
Hope it solves your problem. The link is given for 64 bit OS check your version before installing.